# is Dumbell.js supporting with previous version of highchart?

Tags: highcharts

In our application we are using Highchart version v7.0.0 and can not upgrade it right now. I want to create a dumbell chart and adding Dumbell.js but is is not working for me.

So how we can tackle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the current version the `dumbell` series works totally fine.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dumbbell

All you need to do is import the dumbell module:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/dumbbell.js"></script>
```